# What activity causes the highest level of brain-activity?

Tags: neuroscience

I expect balancing on a tightrope and juggling apples while listening to Mozart would trigger more brain activity than say playing chess, and while there are many ways to measure/define brain activity, still, is there any human activity that is known to be 'the most taxing'?

Brain activity I suppose can be measured as some function of below suggestions, or is there a commonly accepted definition?

- Energy consumption
- Number of neurons/synapses involved
- Amount input 'data' consumed
- Amount of output 'data' generated